# How to trim the innerHTML string upto a specific element inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I want to find out how we can get the `innerHTML` string upto a specific element inside the element.

**Example :**

```
<div id="common-name">
        <p id="P1">This is a paragraph 1.</p>
        <p id="P2" >This is a paragraph 2 .</p>
        <p id="P3">This is a paragraph 3.</p>
</div>
```

Say we want it upto the element with **id: P2** , so output as a *string* would be like :

`<div id="common-name"><p id="P1">This is a paragraph 1.</p>`

(Also if any implementation exists can it be done if the elements didn't have the ID, rather the ref as a object in JavaScript.

**[EDIT]**
The thing i m trying to solve here is, say if i have the element with #p3 as an object and the div container , now i want to get the innerHTML upto the #p2 element. @Jerico's answer will work if things are arranged neatly like p1 -> p2 -> p3, but if the order are interchanged it might not work. Something to work around that?

I tried getting the `innerHTML` content as a string but have no idea how to get the rest of the text after the element, so that i could subtract it from the original string to have the same output.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by having half of an innerHTML string?

Comment: @James So when a user selects some text  i want to inject a empty div with some background color( like highlighting stuff) and then inject it between two elements by modifying the innerHTML content so i need to know how to do it. I can access the selected objects by getting through window.getSelection()

Comment: @Shubhz ... **there is no way around manipulating the DOM directly** by creating and inserting both element and text nodes, based on the data provided by the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object.

Comment: @Shubhz ... What should happen if a user selects following text ... _**"paragraph 1. This is a paragraph 2 . This is a"**_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var container = document.getElementById('common-name'); var targetElement = document.querySelector('#common-name #P2'); var innerHTMLString = '' ; for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) { innerHTMLString += container.children[i].outerHTML; if (container.children[i] === targetElement) break; } console.log(innerHTMLString);
```

Comment: yes this works, i can replace the query selector with my current object reference and it will loop till it reaches that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with to hide a number of elements with a for loop.
I made this code to be reusable and easy to put into the current code.

```js
//Is an array of all elements in div
let container = document.querySelector(".container").children;
let shownElement = 2;

for(let i = 0; i < container.length; i++){
  container[i].setAttribute("id", i + 1);
  console.log(container[i].outerHTML);
  
  if(i == shownElement - 1){
    let reI = i + 1;
    console.log("shown element: " + reI)
  } else {
    container[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Stuff is here.</p>
</div>
```

Edit: I made it so we don't know the order of elements on a random webpage by taking away the P's `ID`. Then we make our own order and hide all elements except the one we want shown. I hope this helps you based on what I understand so far. If it somewhat does be more clear on the asking. (I create the `ID` order on my own because all elements on a webpage are coded in line to work anyway. That's why I'm confused. I'm even more confused after the statement of can we do it with no `ID`? )

Hope this helps :) Upvote if it does.

Comment: I ll integrate and let you know tomorrow , its already late here

Comment: You can click Run code snippet to see if it works here.

Comment: I get the logic , but the main issue being can i get that without knowing the order, like when i call it from a script i will most likely have a object of currentAnchorNode and currentFocusNode, so how do i dynamically segment that from the innerHTML, wait ill update the question with some more details

Comment: The problem is,  i'm developing an extension, so when a random website is loaded i wont have the idea if #p2 is before #p3 or after it, its just a basic example i pasted.

Comment: No .. mainly we would have that object's element reference and we can now do what we want

Comment: @Shubhz I edited my answer for it to be explained and hopefully tailored for you.

Comment: Yes it helps but i cant upvote , it says 15 reputation required. i ll once i get 15 reps

Comment: @Shubhz does it work completely now after my edit?